# In Jenkins pipeline parallel stages, how to promptly kill other stages if one fail?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

If the job failed, I don't have to wait everybody to finish. Is it possible to abort the parallel stages that are still running. They must display as "aborted", not with a red cross icon, since the failed one must be highlighted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `parallelsAlwaysFailFast` to your `options{}` and the whole pipeline will stop if any (parallelized) stage fails.

> [parallelsAlwaysFailFast](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#options)
> Set failfast true for all subsequent parallel
> stages in the pipeline.
>
> For example: options {
> parallelsAlwaysFailFast() }

Example:

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  options {
    parallelsAlwaysFailFast()
  }
  stages {
     ...
  }
}
```

The option highlights the failed stage. Unfortunately the other stages are not displayed as `aborted` they just get the usual (not highlighted) red color.

Comment: I added this option, but the validation failed with this message: `WorkflowScript: 119: Invalid option type "parallelsAlwaysFailFast". Valid option types: [authorizationMatrix, buildDiscarder, catchError, checkoutToSubdirectory, disableConcurrentBuilds, disableResume, durabilityHint, gitLabConnection, gitlabBuilds, gitlabCommitStatus, lock, newContainerPerStage, overrideIndexTriggers, preserveStashes, quietPeriod, rateLimitBuilds, retry, script, skipDefaultCheckout, skipStagesAfterUnstable, timeout, timestamps, waitUntil, withContext, withCredentials, withEnv, ws]`

Comment: This option must be done in the parallel stage itself: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/

Comment: I asked the question and checked that the solution works. Unfortunately I stopped using it, because my users were confused. In the Blue Ocean interface the stages would be aborted without clearing informing it. The aborted stages would display as failed and show the log of another stage. This really confused my users and I thought it would be better to let them wait for each stage to fail and have its own log.

Comment: Only works for FAILED not UNSUCCESSFUL though, right?  And applies to all parallel{} stages and cannot be applied to just some.

Comment: Were you able to achieve this @neves? I also have the same requirement

Comment: Is it possible to apply failfast to only some of the parallel stages? I don't want to apply make failfast to all stages as some are allowed to fail without setting the build.result to failure.